# Plotting a function with different ranges and parameters in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot a function `u(x)` in gnuplot, the function itself looks like this:

```
u(x) = (D) * pi * x

plot    D = 100.0, u(x) title "A, \
        D = 225.0, u(x) title "B"
```

The function with the parameter `D = 100.0` should have a `xrange` reaching from 0 to 1000 and the plot with the parameter `D = 225.0` should have a `xrange` from 0 to 2000.

I have tried the obvious solution

```
u(x) = (D) * pi * x

plot    [0:1000] D = 100.0, u(x) title "A, \
        [0:2000] D = 225.0, u(x) title "B"
```

This attempt generates three graphs, including a graph with a constant value of 225.0

Best Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, I strongly recommend *not* to use axis range specifiers in a plot command. They are often ambiguous and do not achieve what you think they will. For one thing, only the first one in the command is specifically taken to override `xrange`. Subsequent one are instead applied to other axes or to sampling.

The most general way to specify separate ranges for different plot components is to use the pseudofile `'+'` and provide sampling ranges rather than axis ranges.  In your case this would become:

```
u(x) = (D) * pi * x
plot    D=100., [0:1000] '+' using 1:(u(x)) title "A", \
        D = 225.0, [0:2000] '+' using 1:(u(x)) title "B"
```

[image]

Things to note:

- The definitions `D=<value>` do not have a sampling range
- You can if you want specify a sampling interval to go with each range. For example `[1:1000:5]` would sample every 5 on x to yield 200 sampled values.
- This particular plot ends up with an xrange of [0:2000] because it defaults to autoscaling.  You could set this separately beforehand, e.g. `set xrange [-100:2500], and the explicit sampling ranges in the plot command would control which portion of the full x range was drawn into.  See the online demo [piecewise functions](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.5/piecewise.html)

Comment: Thank you for the explanations! Ok, I see using `[xmin:xmax] '+' ...` seems to be the intended way. This is somewhat "hidden" in the documenation: `help plot` --> `range` --> `sampling`. An example directly under `help plot` would be nice. Furthermore, I thought `plot D=100, sin(x)` would be the same as `D=100; plot D, sin(x)`, but apparently it is not. But `plot (D=100), sin(x)` is like the second and `plot D=100 sin(x)` like the first (mind: without comma, which as I read the documentation shouldn't be correct syntax?!). Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

*edit: @Ethan's answer is the intended way to go!*

Welome to StackOverflow! Plot elements are separated by comma (check `help plot`). That's why you are plotting two horizontal lines at `100` and `225` and twice the function `u(x)`. (*apparently wrong! see my comment under Ethan's answer*)

These ranges are also not fully clear to me. According to documentation for each plot-element you should be able to add a range. But apparently, it looks like you have first to plot the function with the larger range. So far, I did not succeed the other way round. Maybe there is a solution which I am not aware of.

Furthermore, you can add your parameter `D` as function input `u(x,D)`.

**Script:**

```
### functions with different parameters and ranges
reset session

u(x,D) = D * pi * x

set xrange[0:2000]
set key invert

plot [0:2000] u(x,225) title "B" lc "blue", \
     [0:1000] u(x,100) title "A" lc "red"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]